# Get selected row column value extjs grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I have a users grid. To delete one, select your row and click a button "delete".
But, this not work.
My code is:

```
var row = userGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
console.log(row.get('dni'))
```

Firefox says:

> TypeError: row.get is not a function

Any idea ?.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is there? Where does `fila` come from?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is good practice to always check `hasSelection()`  like -

```
if (userGrid.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) {
   var row = userGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
   console.log(row.get('dni'))
}
```

Answer (score 7):

perhaps because

> getSelection( ) : Ext.data.Model[]
>
> Returns an ***array*** of the currently selected records.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-getSelection

Comment: @ramiromd In other words try: `var row = userGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];` if you only want the first record selected or this is a single selection grid